# Linux programming: Writing to duplicated socket fails

Tags: c, linux, sockets

After shutting down a socket in write mode, I am trying to write to the duplicated handle. I am getting broken pipe even though both of them have different file descriptors. What is wrong with my code ? or Is that expected behavior ?

```
int clientDupFD = dup(fileDescriptors[0]);

shutdown(fileDescriptors[0], SHUT_WR);

printf ("\n Client: Writing to shutdown(SHUT_WR) socket");

writeOk = write(clientDupFD, msgPtr="Writing message after partial shutdown!", 5);

if(writeOk == -1) {
    printf("\n ERR-%s: write() failed to write msg to socket", strerror(errno));
}
else {
    printf("\n Client: Message '%s' successfully written to socket", msgPtr);
}
```

Also, when I run this through CodeLite, complete output (last printfs) are not getting executed, why ?

Only when I try it through debugger, I can see that the "ERR-Broken pipe" printf statement was executing and the output got printed. I tried using 'fflush(stdout)' as well as 'setbuf(stdout, NULL)'. Both of them didnt work. Can anybody help ?

Comment: Can you explain what you expect to happen and why?

Comment: `shutdown` send a TCP/IP packet notifying the other party about changes to the communication. The underlying network socket changed. The fact that you have two file descriptors referencing the same network socket means that changes to the socket will be visible through both descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

Once a connection's write direction has been shut down, writes can no longer take place on the connection and the implementation is free to communicate to the other end that no more data will arrive. It doesn't matter what handle you use to access the connection -- it's the same connection.

Comment: I found out just now that I should be using a close() call which will keep the other FD alive... Can you also help me with the other question about flushing printfs ?

Comment: The broken pipe error occurs before that `printf`. Fix the broken pipe and your program will run to completion. (It would help a lot if you would put in your question what you're trying to do and what you expect. I have no idea why you called `shutdown` or what you were trying to do, making it hard to help you.)

Comment: I am tring to learn socket programming in linux, so trying out create/close/read/write from sockets. I was just testing what would happen if I wrote to a socket that was shutdown. How do I catch the broken pipe and print the error reason (something similar to try/catch in java ??)

Comment: Ignore the `SIGPIPE` signal and handle the `-1` return from `write` by checking `errno`.

Answer (score 1):

You have shutdown the FD (or more accurately the connection attached to both FDs), so consequently the write fails.

If you are trying to make a socket pair, use `socketpair` (or `pipe`).

Comment: He has shut down the *connection*, not the FD. He has another FD.

Comment: Sure, but there is only one connection shared between the `dup()`d FD.